# Attributes Disabled When Setting Frame Storyboard

Tags: xcode, attributes

[XCode Attributes](http://tinypic.com/r/v6m4hv/6)

Why are the Xcode 4 attributes for setting the frame disabled?

I see many posts on this and I did set the view controller simulated metrics to various settings. However, you can see in the image that the X value is 320 and the Y value is 250!

This would place the view controller way off center. This view controller is in a storyboard so does that make a difference?  If I see to "free form" for simulated metrics I can change the width and height but the X and Y values are stubborn.

Why are the X and Y values weird and NOT changeable?

Comment: I should also mention that I expect the X and Y values to be ZERO! or at least a reflection of simulated elements as in the status bar being 20 pixels high and so the Y value would be 20. I checked the .xibs in my entire project and they are all offset by 300! Weird.

Comment: Also, I am trying to manually set frame values on autorotation in a view since there are some cases where autoresizing will not work. However, how can I know which coordinates to use since the ones in IB are all wonky?!  What origin do .xibs use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to delete this question but answering it so that other poor souls can know the reason for this.

I completely missed the "Origin" setting in the attributes area. It's the box to the left of the coorindate values. For some reason it changed and I didn't notice.

I set it back to the upper-left so that the coordinates can be interpreted correctly.